# Operacion Division entre Arrays

Tags: php

Resulta que tengo dos arrays, uno con calificaciones y otro con el numero con el que necesito dividir las calificaciones del array de calificaciones, la cosa es que no sé cómo puedo realizar esta operación, dividir las calificaciones con los números del otro array...

Adjunto imagen de la impresión del array's, muestra 2 resultados con dos arrays xq lo tengo iterado y existen dos personas en el ejemplo.
Ejemplo:

Dividir -> 22.2 / 3    &&     7.7 / 1 --> Esto sería un alumno

Dividir -> 22.59 / 3   &&   7.2 / 1 --> Segundo alumno

Todo esto para sacar un promedio x bloque y después hacer otras operaciones que ya tengo pensadas como van hacer...

Si me pueden ayudar a saber cómo sería esa operación/código se los agradecería, gracias!!!

PD: La idea seria que quede dinamico es decir:

array1[0] / array2[0];

array1[2] / array2[2];

etc

Codigo Actual:

```
    foreach ($alumns as $a) {
    $nB = CalificationData::numeroBloques($a->alumn_id, $inId);
    $pF = CalificationData::promedioFinal($a->alumn_id, $inId);
    $bloquesPadre = CalificationData::numeroDeBloquesPadre($a->alumn_id, $inId);
    // $numeroDeBloquesPadre = count($bloquesPadre);

    $arrayCalificaciones = [];
    $bloquesHijos = [];

    foreach ($bloquesPadre as $bPadre) {
        $sumaBloquesPadre = CalificationData::sumaBloquesPadre($a->alumn_id, $bPadre->BloquePadre);
        $numeroHijosxBloque = CalificationData::numeroHijosxBloque($a->alumn_id, $bPadre->BloquePadre);
        /**
         *  LLENAMOS LOS DOS ARRAYS VACIOS,  
         *  EL PRIMERO CON LA SUMA DE LAS CALIFICACIONES POR BLOQUE
         *  EL SEGUNDO CON NUMERO DE BLOQUES HIJOS
         */
        array_push($arrayCalificaciones, $sumaBloquesPadre->SumaDeBloque);
        array_push($bloquesHijos, $numeroHijosxBloque->hijosDelBloque);
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arrayCalificaciones);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($bloquesHijos);
}
```

[image: impresión de los arrays]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que el numero de calificaciones siempre es igual al numero de bloques:

```
$resultadosBloques = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayCalificaciones); $i++) {
    array_push($resultadosBloques, $arrayCalificaciones[$i] / $bloqueHijos[$i]);
}
print_r($resultadosBloques);
```

Haciendo la prueba con:

```
$arrayCalificaciones = [22.7, 7.7];
$bloqueHijos = [3, 1];
```

El resultado seria:

```
Array ( [0] => 7.5666666666667 [1] => 7.7 )
```